# Modify list elements whose indices are defined by a list without a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension, vectorization

I want to modify list elements (e.g. putting them equal to 1) whose indices are defined by a list.
A (wrong) idea could be:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,11,22,4]
my_index = [1,3,4]

[my_list[i] = 1 for i in my_index]
```

There is always the **brute** forcing:

```
for i in my_index:
   my_list[i]  = 1
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Is there a way to vectorize this problem? I can also keep different element types from the list.

Comment: You want a vectorized solution with python `lists`?

Comment: Not with pure python, the numpy package supports this if you are desperate to vectorize. Otherwise its probably better to just iterate over the indices as you are already doing.

Comment: Python list comprehensions don't vectorize anything, they are almost equivalent to the corresponding regular for-loop when it comes to performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the "brute forcing", it's readable and clear.
There are ways to do this with e.g. numpy arrays that may be faster. But do you really need more speed?

Comment: I doubt you would gain speed if you include converting to a `np.array' and back to a list.

Comment: yes I would like to have the optimal speed but as @MichaelSzczesny argues a numpy conversion could make the code slower

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny no, you wouldn't. I was talking about the general problem of setting array elements, which is probably faster with numpy arrays. In this toy example, it of course doesn't matter.

Comment: @Siderius speed is not necessary, unless it's necessary.

Comment: @Siderius - I benchmarked your loop solution against `numpy` indexing with 1e6 elements and 1e5 substitutions. I got (loop vs numpy): `11.3ms vs 7.95ms` excluding conversions, `11.3ms vs 117ms` including conversions.

Comment: @JussiNurminen with all respect I know for which purpose this MWE should be oriented. I have asked for the optimal solution both in the answer and in the comments.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny regarding the first result, for "numpy" do you mean a loop with a numpy vector?

Comment: @Siderius - No. I used `my_array = np.array(my_list); my_array[my_index] = 1; my_array.tolist()`.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Have you included in the time `11.3ms vs 7.95ms` the first conversion? If true, it is good for me since I can keep a numpy array instead of converting again in a list (I have added this detail in the edit)

Comment: @Siderius - No, 'excluding' was just `%timeit my_array[my_index] = 1`, which is not very fast with numpy either. Including only the first conversion I get `11.3ms vs 76.2ms`.